# AS3 - Why is my transform.matrix3D null?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, matrix, transform

I have a class named `Box` that extends `Sprite` and when I'm trying to access his `transform.matrix3D` property (indeed is the `matrix3D` property from an `Transform` object) this returns me `null`. Why?

```
package some.place
{
    // ... imports ...

    public class Box extends Sprite
    {
        public function Box() {}

        public function DoSomething():void
        {
            var m:Matrix3D = transform.matrix3D;
            // here m == null !!! Why???
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default 2D object have no `matrix3D`, i.e. if you have not use any 3D  stuff (z property, rotationY,etc ...) with your `DisplayObject` you will have a null matrix.

*N.B. You can also set the matrix3D to null to reset back you object in 2D*

> [The value of the z property of a 2D object is zero and the value of its matrix3D property is null.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html)

Comment: As a quick note, the easiest way to ensure you have a non-null matrix3D property (without otherwise affecting the view of your DisplayObject) is to just set the `displayObjectInstance.z = 1;`.